# Creating new project with compatability library

Tags: android

I can't understand why am I getting this error:

[image]

When another people don't get it and are able to create a new project with inner navigation like that. powered by compatability library:

[image]

PS: I have every single package of android SDK Tools installed on my computer, and they're all up to date

Comment: what are the steps that you follow to get to where you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the wizard doesn't take the compatibility library into consideration.  Set your minimum to 14 and then go and change the manifest after you have created your project and include the compatibility library.